# Magento 1.6.2 Previous Next buttons for moving from one product to another in a sub category

Tags: magento

i want to create a previous next buttons for moving from one product to another in a specific category.

i was using this code in view.phtml, but now its giving undefined variable error for $search_parameter.

```
<?php // Previous and Next product links in product page

$_product = $this->getProduct();

if(!$_product->getCategoryIds())
return; // Don't show Previous and Next if product is not in any category

$cat_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds(); // get all categories where the product is located
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( $cat_ids[0] ); // load first category, you should enhance this, it works for me

$order = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/default_sort_by');
$direction = 'asc'; // asc or desc

$category_products = $cat->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort($order, $direction);
$category_products->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); // 1 or 2
$category_products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',4); // 1.2.3.4

$cat_prod_ids = $category_products->getAllIds(); // get all products from the category
$_product_id = $_product->getId();

$_pos = array_search($_product_id, $cat_prod_ids); // get position of current product
$_next_pos = $_pos+1;
$_prev_pos = $_pos-1;

// get the next product url
if( isset($cat_prod_ids[$_next_pos]) ) {
$_next_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $cat_prod_ids[$_next_pos] );
} else {
$_next_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( reset($cat_prod_ids) );
}
// get the previous product url
if( isset($cat_prod_ids[$_prev_pos]) ) {
$_prev_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $cat_prod_ids[$_prev_pos] );
} else {
$_prev_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( end($cat_prod_ids) );
}
?>                



<div class="clear"></div>
 <!--PREVIOUS BUTTON NEXT BUTTON STARTS-->
 <div class="previousNext">

<?php if($_prev_prod != NULL): ?>
<a href="<?php print $_prev_prod->getUrlPath(); if($search_parameter):?>?search=1<?php endif;?>"><span style="margin-right: 270px;"><?php echo $this->__('<< PREVIOUS') ?></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_next_prod != NULL): ?>
<a href="<?php print $_next_prod->getUrlPath(); if($search_parameter):?>?search=1<?php endif;?>"><span style="margin-left: 270px;"><?php echo $this->__('NEXT >>') ?></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!--PREVIOUS BUTTON NEXT BUTTON ENDS-->
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: if you have just copy-pasted this code from somewhere, you have probably missed out a few lines.

Comment: thnks guys,i took this code from this site http://www.xpressbangla.com/how-to-get-previous-next-product-buttons-on-product-view-page-in-magento/

Comment: ive tried using the above code by eliminating the $search_parameter completely. The code works... but when it reaches the end of products in a category it shows next category product but with link to present category... thus giving a Page error. Thanks guys..

Answer (score -2):

hey finally got the above code to work on my website..

Following are the steps followed:

STEP1: While adding products MAKE SURE each product is added to ONE CATEGORY only. A product in more than one category, this code does not work. IN other words, if you are adding a product to say Cat1 > Subcat1 > subsubcat2, make sure you only add it to subsubcat2. THan you will be able to move next previous within that sub sub cat.

STEP2: Open view.phtml and add the following code:

```
<?php // Previous and Next product links in product page

$_product = $this->getProduct();


if(!$_product->getCategoryIds())
return; // Don't show Previous and Next if product is not in any category

$cat_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds(); // get all categories where the product is   located
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( $cat_ids[0] ); // load first category, you should enhance this, it works for me

$order = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/default_sort_by');
$direction = 'desc'; // asc or desc

$category_products = $cat->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort($order,   $direction);
$category_products->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); // 1 or 2
$category_products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',4); // 1.2.3.4

$cat_prod_ids = $category_products->getAllIds(); // get all products from the category
$_product_id = $_product->getId();

$_pos = array_search($_product_id, $cat_prod_ids); // get position of current product
$_next_pos = $_pos+1;
$_prev_pos = $_pos-1;

// get the next product url
if( isset($cat_prod_ids[$_next_pos]) ) {
$_next_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $cat_prod_ids[$_next_pos] );
} else {
$_next_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( reset($cat_prod_ids) );
}
// get the previous product url
if( isset($cat_prod_ids[$_prev_pos]) ) {
$_prev_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $cat_prod_ids[$_prev_pos] );
} else {
$_prev_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( end($cat_prod_ids) );
}
?>
```

STEP3: Add the PREVIOS and NEXT buttons code

```
 <!--PREVIOUS BUTTON NEXT BUTTON STARTS-->
 <div class="previousNext">

<?php if($_prev_prod != NULL): ?>
<a href="<?php print $_prev_prod->getUrlPath();?>"><span style="margin-right: 270px;"><?php echo $this->__('<< PREVIOUS') ?></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_next_prod != NULL): ?>
<a href="<?php print $_next_prod->getUrlPath();?>"><span style="margin-left: 270px;"><?php echo $this->__('NEXT >>') ?></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!--PREVIOUS BUTTON NEXT BUTTON ENDS-->
```

STEP4: Add css style to the links

```
<style>
.previousNext {width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right;  }
.previousNext a:link {font-size: 12px; color:#ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none}
.previousNext a:visited {font-size: 12px; color:#ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none}
.previousNext a:hover {font-size: 12px; color:#ff9900; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline}
.previousNext a:active {font-size: 12px; color:#ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none}
</style>
```

Position the previous next buttons ideally inside the product-essential div (default template)

And your next or previos project is ready work...

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is unbelievably bad code.  You template files should never contain code like this.